# Popover doesn't show up on dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a custom [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers):

popover:

```
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">Add new tab</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
     <form class="form-inline" id="pop-form" method="POST" action="../admin/FLT_add_tab.do">
          <div class="form-group">
             <!-- my form -->
             <input type="text" name="newTab" id="newTab" required="required" pattern="^[\S\s]{3,25}[A-z]+$" title="Only accept alphabet characters and length is minimum of 3 and max of 25 " placeholder="Tab name.."/>
             <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i></button>
             <button class="btn" type="button" onClick="popRemove();" ><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
          </div>
       <p></p>
       <p style="color:red" id="error-message"></p>
     </form>
</div>
```

My div is dynamically generated from the jQuery UI from [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) this is the structure of the sortable:

```
<div class="question-constructor multiple-choice-problem">
     <label for="textbox" class="question-label"> #. Edit this to define question: </label>
     <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-1" class="question-radio" style="float:left;"><label for="option-1-1">Thing 1</label>
     <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-2" class="question-radio" style="float:left;"><label for="option-1-2">Thing 1</label>
     <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-3" class="question-radio" style="float:left;"><label for="option-1-3">Thing 1</label>
     <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-4" class="question-radio" style="float:left;"><label for="option-1-4"> Thing 1</label>
</div>
```

But for some reason the popover doesn't show:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#preview .question-constructor', function( event ) {

        var id =  $('#preview .question-constructor').index(this);

        $('#preview .question-constructor').each( function() {
            if( $('#preview .question-constructor').index(this) == id ) {
                $(this).popover('show');
                console.log('true' +$('#preview .question-constructor').index(this) );
            } else {
                console.log('not' +$('#preview .question-constructor').index(this) );
            }
        }); 

        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#preview .question-constructor').each( function() {
        $(this).popover({ 
            html : true,
            trigger : 'manual',
            title : function() {
                return $("#popover-head").html();
            },
            content: function() {
                return $("#popover-content").html();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The `#preview` id is the id of the sortable div, and the `.question-constructor` class is the div inside the sortable where the popover should show up. My guess is the initialization of the popover is wrong but I couldn't get it right.

What I want to do is:

1. When an item ( i.e item 1 ) is clicked show popover
2. But when another item ( i.e item 2 ) is clicked hide all other popover and show the popover beside this item.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwy4A/) when I put the initialization on the onClick event it shows the popover but not to my desire behavior.

Comment: have u added the bootstrap popover js file in your page's head?

Comment: @SherKhan yes. I was able to use it on other button

Comment: @SherKhan please check my fiddle

Comment: ok checking  the fiddle

Comment: @SherKhan find anyhing?

Comment: I still didn't get ur problem accurately. It generates popover once its  cloned and then it generates popover for one then not for second one. Sp please explain a bit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40866/discussion-between-user2785929-and-sher-khan)

Comment: .question-constructor is not a child of #preview div.... ? so your click event is not responding at all in jsfiddle

Comment: @SherKhan please see my chat in the disscussion

Comment: @rusln `.question-constructor` will be appended to `#preview div` because of the after dragging it from the **side** to the **main**

Answer (score 0):

does this help ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/AWF82/

```
…
$("#preview").on('click', '.question-constructor', function(e) {        
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".question-constructor").not(this).popover('hide');
    });
…

receive: function (ev, ui) {
            //init popover
            $(this).data().sortable.currentItem.popover({
                content: "hallo world"
            });
        }
```

Comment: I was happy to see your answer because that is exactly what I need. but why do I get this error in my console? `TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentItem' of undefined`. But on the fiddle it is perfectly working?

Comment: can i see your exact code ? somehow sortable property is not defined in data property of the sortable list..

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REPwR/). I don't know why in the fiddle it works

Comment: To be honest, i have no idea, it could be the version of jQuery but i doubt that. Or something else.